# Why is my recursive maze algorithm not back tracking?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, libgdx, path-finding

Forgive me i'm new to recursion but as far as i understand this should work, but it doesn't. I made this method that calls itself recursively when successfully found a path:

```
private void RandStep(Point pos)
    {       
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(directions), rand); //Incorrect, should have a local directions array. Nothing to do with the question though.
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.length;i++)
        {
            //Check if the positions are within map bounds.
            if (pos.x + directions[i].x >= 0 && pos.x + directions[i].x < width && pos.y + directions[i].y >= 0 && pos.y + directions[i].y < height)
            {
                //Check if the position is unvisited.
                if (!mazeMap[pos.x + directions[i].x][pos.y + directions[i].y].visited)
                {
                    //Break walls this tile.
                    CarvePassage(pos, directions[i]);
                    mazeMap[pos.x + directions[i].x][pos.y + directions[i].y].visited = true;
                    position.setLocation(pos.x + directions[i].x, pos.y + directions[i].y);
                    RandStep(position);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- First it randomizes an array with 4 directions.
- Then i loop through the array to find a possible direction.
- Then It checks if the direction found is valid otherwise it goes to the next direction in the array
- When it is valid it calls another method that carves the wall of the current tile and the next tile.
- It changes the current position to the next and sets it's flag to visited.
- Finally it calls itself again to make the next step.

This all works until the first time it gets stuck between visited cells or map bounds. If i understand recursion correctly it should exit this method and go to the previous run of `RandStep` and finish the direction loop. When it does not find any valid cells there: it again should exit and finish the loop in the previous `RandStep`. This should be repeated until it finished the direction loop of the very first `RandStep` run.

Like i said, it stops at the moment it cannot find any valid cells. It does not continue the previous methods on the recursion stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply, it's because you don't step back!

```
position.setLocation(pos.x + directions[i].x, pos.y + directions[i].y);
RandStep(position);
```

Should be something like:

```
position.setLocation(pos.x + directions[i].x, pos.y + directions[i].y);
RandStep(position);
position.setLocation(pos.x - directions[i].x, pos.y - directions[i].y);
```

As a bit of intuition, think about what happens in the base case of recursion. all tiles around you are visited, and you are at a dead end. That situation looks like:

```
 _
| |
|x|
```

(`x` = "you are here")

Then, `position.setLocation(pos.x + directions[i].x, pos.y + directions[i].y);` puts you here:

```
 _
|x|
| |
```

Then, `RandStep(position);` does *nothing* since all locations around you are explored. So the next thing you want to do is step backwards, which is accomplished by something like: `position.setLocation(pos.x - directions[i].x, pos.y - directions[i].y);`.

Comment: Yeah obvious, or use a local position for each method. Thanks!

Comment: Recursion is far from obvious, actually :)

Comment: It is, i have been breaking my head over this one since Costa Rica made there 2nd goal :D. But actually it still does not work, it does not backtrack completely and fill the complete map.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, this probably won't work. I'd sort of need to see the rest of the code to make any further suggestions. But I think my suggestion is the general problem.

Comment: Your initial answer was correct i think. I am actually stepping on the final tile, check all the tiles then fails and goes back. Then it should reverse the direction there to step back. But does better, but does not fill the complete map, somehow.

Comment: I got it, your initial answer was good. I had to create local directions array because it was using the order of the last method on the recursive stack.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look at what is happening under the hood. Assuming you are familiar with what a heap and a stack are, the variable `position` resides on the `heap`, as it is not local to your function `RandStep`. On the other hand, `pos` is local, so it resides on the stack. With every recursive call, a new stack frame is allocated (from frameA to frameC). I represent positions as single values for the sake of brevity. Let's say that you start from position 0, and then break the walls towards position 1. What happens is that a new frame is allocated for the new value of `pos`, but `position`is overwritten. The same when you transition from position 1 to position 2. Let's say that from position 2 there's nowhere to go, so we need to trace back. Then frameC is deallocated. However, instead of using the value of `pos` in the top frame (which is frameB now), your call to `RandStep` was made on `position`, so the value that you use is the one on the heap, which remained unchanged despite the frame deallocation.

"Stepping back" as suggested by Intredasting acutally means manually updating the heap, so that `position` follows the same evolution as `pos`. In my opinion, that defeats the purpose of recursion. Its beauty is that it takes care itself of the stepping back part by deallocation.

In conclusion, what you need to do is avoid changing the heap at all in recursive functions.

```
|STACK          |   |STACK         |    |STACK          |
|               |   |              |    |               |
|               |   |              |    |frameC: pos = 2|---> got stuck, deallocate frame
|               |   |frameB: pos=1 |    |frameB: pos = 1|     and backtrack
|frameA: pos=0  |   |frameA: pos=0 |    |frameA: pos = 0|
|---------------|   |--------------|    |---------------|
|HEAP           |   |HEAP          |    |HEAP           |
|position = 0   |   |position=1    |    |position = 2   |
|               |   |              |    |               |
|               |   |              |    |               |
-----------------   ----------------    -----------------
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what happened with the directions array too, made an edit/comment in my initial code. Thanks for explaining in depth.